# New installation of jpgraph not display colours and "show values" properly

Tags: php, colors, apache2, ubuntu-10.04, jpgraph

I had a fully function Ubuntu 10.04 server running Apache/php2 and jpgraph. Unfortunately, the server died and now I have rebuilt it, but jpgraphing doesn't seem to be functioning properly anymore.
The two issues that I have found are:
1- the colors selected doesn't match what is actually displayed.See example from jpgraph:
http://www.philserver.faure.ca/~philippe/Solar/examples/show-example.php?target=example21.php

2- the "show value" command doesn't show the values on the graphs anymore. See exmaple from jpgraph:
http://www.philserver.faure.ca/~philippe/Solar/examples/show-example.php?target=example3.4.1.php

I had written a website that worked a expected, but now this new installation isn't functioning properly.  I have search Google, jpgraph website and even contacted them without any information.  I don't even know where to start looking for more help.

Has someone come across this before?  Does someone know where to start searching for a solution?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was asked in this forum previously. You have to put them after the Add. Even their examples don't work!

Look at [Changing the display settings of line/bar graphs Chapter 29. Attention](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch29s02.html) in the manual.